# Eloqua- Update/Delete bulk campaigns using API

Tags: eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

There are so many outdated information on Eloqua Bulk and REST API.However, I have found a resource which seems to be the latest one:

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAC/index.html

I have retrieved a list of campaigns using REST API.Here is what I am trying to accomplish using REST or Bulk API: I have to retrieve a list of campaigns matching certain criteria and then make changes to a field in all campaigns, then update the list of Campaigns using BULK or REST API.

is it possible to update the list of Campaigns using Bulk or REST API?Can I delete the list of Campaigns using Bulk or REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the REST/Bulk documentation is weak.

Unfortunately, you can not update the list. Why ?

**Bulk API:**

- is designed to act on primitive data (contact, account, CO, and his own metadata aka imports/exports/syncs)
- Campaigns are complex data, so they are not exposed in Bulk.

**REST API:**

- Give you access to the list of all campaigns (good news right ?)
- Data can be modified in REST but only one by one

REST is not designed for mass update. Even for contacts !

The answer is no: you can not update the list of campaigns using Bulk or REST API (not without using a program doing iteration for you).

Answer (score 2):

Campaigns are not exposed in the bulk API. You'll have to use the rest API and there's no support for batch updates or deletes.